# Issues with the Live Agent Queue

Tags: liveagent

I'm attempting to use the chat queue position as noted below, but all I'm getting is the text in testing, even when all agents are at capacity. I imagine it's something simple, but any help would be amazing! Thank you!

```
<table id="waitingMessage" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
    <td><br/><br/>Please wait while you are connected to an available agent. You are currently #
        <liveAgent:clientChatQueuePosition/></td><br/>
    <br/>     
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please verify if you are using this for buttons of the type **Push Routing**. Secondly, this tag must be used within **liveAgent:clientChat**

The liveAgent:clientChatQueuePosition component shows where in the chat queue a visitor is. In order for a chat to enter the queue:

1.The button from which the chat was requested must have queuing enabled.

2.All online agents (with the relevant skills, if applicable) must be at capacity, causing a queue to form.
3.The chat must be in the queue and not yet assigned to an agent.

If all three of these conditions aren’t met, liveAgent:clientChatQueuePosition doesn't display a value.